# Nodejs: Moongoose can't find the object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

So I have a mongodb on mongolabs that looks something like this:

under the collection "news"

```
 [{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "542aab88e4b0e67da1edd1bd"
},
"year": 2014,
"data": {
     "someinfo":"cool info"
 }
}]
```

And on node I have the following:

```
 //dependencies
 var mongoose = require("mongoose");
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 //Setting up the schemas
    var newsSchema = new Schema({
        year: String, 
        data: Object
    });
    mongoose.model('news',newsSchema);

  //routes
  var mongolabs = express.Router();
  mongolabs.route('/List/:type1/:year')
  .get(function(req, res){
           mongoose.model(req.params.type1).find({year:req.params.year}, function(err,suc) {
            res.jsonp(suc);
           });
    });
    app.use('/mongo', mongolabs);
```

unfortunately when I go http:///mongo/List/news/2014, it returns empty.
I already tried everything I can think of, needless to say I am a newbie to mongoose, node and mongodb.

Comment: In `newsSchema`, shouldn't it be `year: Number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to query for a `number` value with a `string` value, hence the empty results.

Try casting the `req.params.years` as a number by adding the `unary plus` before your param.

```
{ year: +req.params.year }
```

You also could use the parseInt() function:

```
var year = parseInt(req.params.years, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're passing `null` to the `.find()` method.

You're doing this:

```
{ year: req.params.type1.year }
```

,when you should be doing:

```
{ year: req.params.year }
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when I was moving my code here.

Comment: Ok then. So assuming you have data in your db, if you run a `db.news.find({year: "2014"})`, what do you get? When you put a `console.log()` inside the `.get` callback, do you see it in the logs?